# Why do I need to disable `foreign_key_checks` for MySQL 8 to be able to use INPLACE algorithm when adding foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, innodb, mysql-8.0

According to MySQL 8 [online DDL operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-foreign-key-operations) documentation, when adding a new foreign key constraint, the INPLACE algorithm is supported only if `foreign_key_checks` is disabled.

Given that setting `set foreign_key_checks=0` only affects the current session and while the foreign key is being created it’s not possible to use the same session to do a parallel job, **wouldn’t be possible to MySQL automatically set this before creating a foreign key to always be able to use the INPLACE algorithm instead of COPY?** What am I missing? Is it somewhat related to index creation that happens automatically during a foreign key creation?

Comment: *Is it somewhat related to index creation that happens automatically during a foreign key creation?* No, secondary index creation may be in-place in any case and hence cannot influence.

Comment: Adding a FK could discover a violation.  Violations can only be check by a long tedious lookup for every row.  `INPLACE` implies a faster operation than that.

Comment: @RickJames, it seems strange to me why copying the entire table (algorithm=copy) would be better than: 1. db temporary stop writes while check if current data is valid. 2. start the inplace operation as usual. Disclaimer: I'm saying that with very few knowledge on DB architecture. I'm almost at the "typical customer level" saying: "it's easy, it's just a button!". :P

Comment: @IsraelFonseca - `COPY` usually implies rebuilding the indexes.  When adding an FK, there is no assurance that the references are valid.  Nor do I know all the details of `ALTER`.  (In the old days, there was only one flavor of ALTER.  It would Create new table, copy all the data over, build the indexes, Rename.)